# How to make apidoc.json parameters required?

Tags: json, api-doc

Super simple but I can't find the docs on how to mark a parameter as **required** when I markup my document to generate an api-doc (using the package @: http://apidocjs.com)

```
// My APIDOC markup in my PHP doc

 * @apiParam {String} [type] comma delimited list of any or all of: contests, deals, coupons
```

... which generates the following html:

[image]

I want the `optional` as shown  to become `required`. What is the markup for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Turns out you just remove the [] brackets around the variable

```
 * @apiParam {String} required_variable comma delimited list of any or all of: contests, deals, coupons
```